# Is it possible to install a node in a python app platform?

Tags: digital-ocean

I have a Python application deployed in the app platform, but I need a javascript runtime, for example a node, can I somehow install it additionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Platform uses containers.

For the [natively-supported](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/app-platform/languages-frameworks/) platforms|languages, DO has created|used buildpacks to build the container image for your app but, if these buildpacks are insufficient for your needs, you can write and use a [`Dockerfile`](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/app-platform/languages-frameworks/docker/) directly.

You will then use the `spec.yaml` to define HTTP ports, healthchecks, routes etc.

When App Platform launched, I blogged an example using [Rust](https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/201008/) as this is not natively-supported.

Comment: do you know how I can add environment variables to docker that are set in components?

Comment: Respectfully, this is now a different question. The documentation does a good job of explaining this: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/app-platform/how-to/use-environment-variables/#define-build-time-environment-variables